# Scala: immutable Map is changing its values

Tags: scala, immutability

I am writing a code to determine a k-colorable Graph. I am using ***immutable Maps to determine vertices colors on backtracking.***

On the second interaction of a flatMap loop, my Map lost an element. I couldn't be able to write a more concise example that would present the same bug, then here it is my entire code:

```scala
import scala.collection.immutable
import scala.collection.mutable

class GraphUndirected[Vertex](vertices: Set[Vertex], edges: Set[(Vertex, Vertex)]) {
  private val adjacencyList: Map[Vertex, Set[Vertex]] =
    (
      edges.flatMap{ case (a, b) => {Seq( (a, Set(b)), (b, Set(a)))}}
        ++ vertices.map((_, Set()))
      )
      .groupBy(_._1)
      .mapValues(
        _.map(_._2)
          .reduce(_ ++ _)
          .toSet
      )

  override def toString(): String = adjacencyList.toString

  def kColorable[C](colors: Set[C]): Option[Map[Vertex, C]] = {
    vertices.toSeq.view.flatMap( v => {
      val colorsMap = immutable.Map[Vertex,C]()
      kColorable[C](colors, v, colorsMap)
    }).headOption
  }

  def kColorable[C](colors: Set[C], v: Vertex, colorMap: Map[Vertex, C]): Option[Map[Vertex, C]] = {
    println(v, colorMap)

    colors.toSeq.view.flatMap( c => {
      if (kColorableIsSafe[C](c, v, colorMap)) {
        val newColorMap = colorMap + (v -> c)
        println("\tnewColorMap", newColorMap)

        if (newColorMap.size == vertices.size) {
          Some(newColorMap)
        } else {
          adjacencyList(v).toSeq.view.flatMap( u => {
            println("\t\tnewColorMap", newColorMap)

            if (newColorMap.contains(u)) {
              None
            } else {
              kColorable[C](colors, u, newColorMap)
            }
          }).headOption
        }
      } else {
        None
      }
    }).headOption
  }

  def kColorableIsSafe[C](c: C, v: Vertex, colorMap: Map[Vertex, C]): Boolean = {
    adjacencyList(v).forall( u => {
      (!colorMap.contains(u)) ||
        (colorMap(u) != c)
    })
  }
}

val myGraph1 = new GraphUndirected[Int](
  Set(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  Set(
    (1,2),
    (3,2), (3,4),
    (5,7), (5,9),
    (6,4),
    (8,2), (8,9)
  )
)
println(myGraph1.kColorable[String](Set("BLACK", "WHITE")))
```

Running this code will produce:

```
(5,Map())
(       newColorMap,Map(5 -> BLACK))
(               newColorMap,Map(5 -> BLACK))
(7,Map(5 -> BLACK))
(       newColorMap,Map(5 -> BLACK, 7 -> WHITE))
(               newColorMap,Map(5 -> BLACK, 7 -> WHITE))
(               newColorMap,Map(5 -> BLACK))
(9,Map(5 -> BLACK))
```

It does not make sense for me. In the first interaction it prints `newColorMap,Map(5 -> BLACK, 7 -> WHITE)`, but in the second the "7->WHITE" is gone `newColorMap,Map(5 -> BLACK)`.

`newColorMap` wasn't supposed to be immutable, not changing its value?

---

My Scala version:

```
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.12.2 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

Comment: Be careful with `mapValues` because the function you give it is called every time you read a value from the `Map`. It is better to use a normal `map` if you are going to access the values more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems bug-free to me. It returns the expected output. What is deceptive is the way you have chosen to output the internal state of your program as you step through it.

To understand what's going on, try running this version of the same program. Just copy and paste the code into Kcolor.scala, drop it in its folder and type in

```
scalac Kcolor.scala
scala Kcolor
```

Here are the contents of Kcolor.scala

```
import scala.collection.immutable

object Kcolor extends App {

  val myGraph1 = new GraphUndirected[Int](
    Set(5,7,9),
    Set((5,7), (5,9))
  )
  println(myGraph1.kColorable[String](Set("BLACK", "WHITE")))

}

class GraphUndirected[Vertex](vertices: Set[Vertex], edges: Set[(Vertex, Vertex)]) {
  val adjacencyList: Map[Vertex, Set[Vertex]] =
    (
      edges.flatMap{ case (a, b) => {Seq( (a, Set(b)), (b, Set(a)))}}
        ++ vertices.map((_, Set()))
      )
      .groupBy(_._1)
      .mapValues(
        _.map(_._2)
          .reduce(_ ++ _)
          .toSet
      )

  override def toString(): String = adjacencyList.toString

  def kColorable[C](colors: Set[C]): Option[Map[Vertex, C]] = {
    vertices.flatMap( v => {
      val colorsMap = immutable.Map[Vertex,C]()
      kColorable[C](colors, v, colorsMap)
    }).headOption
  }

  def kColorable[C](colors: Set[C], v: Vertex, colorMap: Map[Vertex, C]): Option[Map[Vertex, C]] = {
    println(v, colorMap)

    val res = colors.flatMap( c => {
      if (kColorableIsSafe[C](c, v, colorMap)) {
        val newColorMap = colorMap + (v -> c)
        println("\tnewColorMap", v, c, newColorMap)

        if (newColorMap.size == vertices.size) {
          Some(newColorMap)
        } else {
          val res1 = adjacencyList(v).flatMap( u => {
            println("\t\tnewColorMap", u, newColorMap)

            if (newColorMap.contains(u)) {
              None
            } else {
              kColorable[C](colors, u, newColorMap)
            }
          })
          println(res1)
          res1.headOption
        }
      } else {
        None
      }
    }).headOption
    println("end")
    res
  }

  def kColorableIsSafe[C](c: C, v: Vertex, colorMap: Map[Vertex, C]): Boolean = {
    adjacencyList(v).forall( u => {
      (!colorMap.contains(u)) ||
        (colorMap(u) != c)
    })
  }
}
```

I have included the first few lines of the output:

```
(5,Map())
(       newColorMap,5,BLACK,Map(5 -> BLACK))
(               newColorMap,7,Map(5 -> BLACK))
(7,Map(5 -> BLACK))
(       newColorMap,7,WHITE,Map(5 -> BLACK, 7 -> WHITE))
(               newColorMap,5,Map(5 -> BLACK, 7 -> WHITE))
Set()
end
(               newColorMap,9,Map(5 -> BLACK))
(9,Map(5 -> BLACK))
(       newColorMap,9,WHITE,Map(5 -> BLACK, 9 -> WHITE))
(               newColorMap,5,Map(5 -> BLACK, 9 -> WHITE))
Set()
end
```

What the program is doing is that it's reaching the end of the flatMap without being able to create a colorized map, and it is outputting None. So between the line

```
(               newColorMap,5,Map(5 -> BLACK, 7 -> WHITE))
```

and

```
(               newColorMap,9,Map(5 -> BLACK))
```

it is reaching the end of the current flatMap and jumping back to the next iteration of the outer loop.

Your program is very interesting. I had fun thinking about it. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thank you very much @user6337!
By the way I was doing something wrong with my k-colorable code. This one seems to work fine: https://gist.github.com/leonardonsantos/2db136ad8c9e8f0f029effa44244de74
I was doing a DFS, which is not necessary.

Comment: @Leonardo Thanks for sharing your updated code. The terseness compared to the original version is a thing of beauty.